# How to create shared memory objects with joblib on linux?

Tags: python, linux, numpy, joblib, numpy-memmap

I am working through the [`joblib` shared memory tutorial](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auto_examples/parallel_memmap.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-parallel-memmap-py).  It seems that [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) dumps data to disk, which is unfortunate.  However, using [ramfs](https://stackpointer.io/unix/linux-create-ram-disk-filesystem/438/) it should be theoretically possible to share memory between joblib processes on a linux box.

Is there a convenient pipeline for:

1. Create a ramfs filesystem just big enough to hold a particular shape/dtype ndarray
2. `memmap` that ndarray to that ramfs
3. Allow me to do what I want with it
4. Clean up the `memmap`
5. Clean up the ramfs

I can invoke a bunch of `subprocess.call(["mount",...])` type stuff, but this seems overly complex.  Is there a better way to do this thing?

Comment: If anyone knows of a "ramfs"-relevant tag to add to this question, that would be super.